# Interact.js drag and drop not working in IE9 browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, polyfills

Getting below error when I was trying to drag.

```
  event.target.classList.add('drop-active');

" Unable to get property 'add' of undefined or null reference"
```

I have used polyfill classList.js to fix this but it doesn't work.

Please help me on this. I am getting this error only in ie9 browser.

Comment: IE9 doesn't support `classList`. You can patch it though.

Comment: ...you have a `polyfills` tag, so it would seem you already know what to look for.

Comment: Hi @Squint,
Thanks for your quick replay.

I have used classList.js polyfill but still its not working.
Let me know if there is any other way to fix this.

Comment: If the polyfill isn't working, then you're likely applying it incorrectly. You'll need to show what you're doing.

Comment: Hi,

This is fixed now, thank for your help.

Comment: If it's fixed, can you add the solution here so others can benefit from it please? I'm having the same problem.